# I can use Wi-Fi to browse with my phone but I can't connect to WhatsApp using the Wi-Fi.

Tags: wi-fi

When I am connected to school Wi-Fi, I can browse but I cannot connect to WhatsApp or Instagram.  When I am connected to Wi-Fi in other places, both WhatsApp and Instagram work perfectly fine. The only way one can access WhatsApp and Instagram using the school Wi-Fi is using a rooted phone and I  don't want to root mine. 
Please help.

Comment: Would you mention how root is related to the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your school has a firewall or blacklist, that blocks these sites?
Is your friend using a vpn or something like that? These are sometimes easier to configure with root, than without.